# Problems installing pymavlink 2.4.8

Tags: dronekit

I'm new to this. I was trying to run sitl simulation and was installing all the packages. I tried to install an older version of pymavlink on ubuntu because newer seem to have problems. And many others did that in tutorials. I ran `sudo pip3 install pymavlink==2.4.8` and got such errors:

```
Collecting pymavlink==2.4.8
  Using cached pymavlink-2.4.8.tar.gz (3.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pymavlink==2.4.8) (0.18.3)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pymavlink==2.4.8) (4.9.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: pymavlink
  Building wheel for pymavlink (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [46 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      Using message definitions from /tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/message_definitions
      Building /tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/message_definitions/v1.0/ardupilotmega.xml for protocol 1.0
      WARNING: Unable to load XML validator libraries. XML validation will not be performed
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/setup.py", line 109, in <module>
          setup (name = 'pymavlink',
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/setup.py", line 103, in run
          generate_content()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/setup.py", line 64, in generate_content
          if not mavgen.mavgen_python_dialect(dialect, mavparse.PROTOCOL_1_0):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/generator/mavgen.py", line 247, in mavgen_python_dialect
          if not mavgen(opts, [xml]):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/generator/mavgen.py", line 142, in mavgen
          xml.append(mavparse.MAVXML(fname, opts.wire_protocol))
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/generator/mavparse.py", line 420, in __init__
          m.crc_extra = message_checksum(m)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/generator/mavparse.py", line 447, in message_checksum
          crc.accumulate_str(msg.name + ' ')
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/generator/mavcrc.py", line 34, in accumulate_str
          bytes.fromstring(buf)
      AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'fromstring'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymavlink
  Running setup.py clean for pymavlink
Failed to build pymavlink
Installing collected packages: pymavlink
  Running setup.py install for pymavlink ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pymavlink did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [50 lines of output]
      running install
      /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      Using message definitions from /tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/message_definitions
      Building /tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/message_definitions/v1.0/ardupilotmega.xml for protocol 1.0
      WARNING: Unable to load XML validator libraries. XML validation will not be performed
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/setup.py", line 109, in <module>
          setup (name = 'pymavlink',
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 68, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/command/install.py", line 619, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/setup.py", line 103, in run
          generate_content()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/setup.py", line 64, in generate_content
          if not mavgen.mavgen_python_dialect(dialect, mavparse.PROTOCOL_1_0):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/generator/mavgen.py", line 247, in mavgen_python_dialect
          if not mavgen(opts, [xml]):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/generator/mavgen.py", line 142, in mavgen
          xml.append(mavparse.MAVXML(fname, opts.wire_protocol))
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/generator/mavparse.py", line 420, in __init__
          m.crc_extra = message_checksum(m)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/generator/mavparse.py", line 447, in message_checksum
          crc.accumulate_str(msg.name + ' ')
        File "/tmp/pip-install-u688fu4a/pymavlink_14df38e43e034876b23652c0fb467231/generator/mavcrc.py", line 34, in accumulate_str
          bytes.fromstring(buf)
      AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'fromstring'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pymavlink

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
emil618@LAPTOP-OAM6O1U6:~$ sudo pip install pymavlink==2.4.8
Collecting pymavlink==2.4.8
  Using cached pymavlink-2.4.8.tar.gz (3.6 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pymavlink==2.4.8) (0.18.3)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from pymavlink==2.4.8) (4.9.2)
Building wheels for collected packages: pymavlink
  Building wheel for pymavlink (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [46 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      Using message definitions from /tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/message_definitions
      Building /tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/message_definitions/v1.0/ardupilotmega.xml for protocol 1.0
      WARNING: Unable to load XML validator libraries. XML validation will not be performed
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/setup.py", line 109, in <module>
          setup (name = 'pymavlink',
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/setup.py", line 103, in run
          generate_content()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/setup.py", line 64, in generate_content
          if not mavgen.mavgen_python_dialect(dialect, mavparse.PROTOCOL_1_0):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/generator/mavgen.py", line 247, in mavgen_python_dialect
          if not mavgen(opts, [xml]):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/generator/mavgen.py", line 142, in mavgen
          xml.append(mavparse.MAVXML(fname, opts.wire_protocol))
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/generator/mavparse.py", line 420, in __init__
          m.crc_extra = message_checksum(m)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/generator/mavparse.py", line 447, in message_checksum
          crc.accumulate_str(msg.name + ' ')
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/generator/mavcrc.py", line 34, in accumulate_str
          bytes.fromstring(buf)
      AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'fromstring'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymavlink
  Running setup.py clean for pymavlink
Failed to build pymavlink
Installing collected packages: pymavlink
  Running setup.py install for pymavlink ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pymavlink did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [50 lines of output]
      running install
      /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      Using message definitions from /tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/message_definitions
      Building /tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/message_definitions/v1.0/ardupilotmega.xml for protocol 1.0
      WARNING: Unable to load XML validator libraries. XML validation will not be performed
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/setup.py", line 109, in <module>
          setup (name = 'pymavlink',
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 68, in run
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/command/install.py", line 619, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/usr/lib/python3.10/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/setup.py", line 103, in run
          generate_content()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/setup.py", line 64, in generate_content
          if not mavgen.mavgen_python_dialect(dialect, mavparse.PROTOCOL_1_0):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/generator/mavgen.py", line 247, in mavgen_python_dialect
          if not mavgen(opts, [xml]):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/generator/mavgen.py", line 142, in mavgen
          xml.append(mavparse.MAVXML(fname, opts.wire_protocol))
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/generator/mavparse.py", line 420, in __init__
          m.crc_extra = message_checksum(m)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/generator/mavparse.py", line 447, in message_checksum
          crc.accumulate_str(msg.name + ' ')
        File "/tmp/pip-install-muoyzd8q/pymavlink_e9818d02e995458cb64b6a1f6e3d3da0/generator/mavcrc.py", line 34, in accumulate_str
          bytes.fromstring(buf)
      AttributeError: 'array.array' object has no attribute 'fromstring'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pymavlink

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

The package doesn't seem to be problematic. Maybe it just doesn't work with the python version. I have 3.10.6

Comment: have you considered docker containers?

Answer (score 0):

While I do know from experience, pymavlink 2.4.8 isn't supported by python 3.10, according to these guys ([1](https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python/issues/1083#issuecomment-932943326), [2](https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python/issues/1083#issuecomment-1342419288)) you'll need to use Python 3.6 or below.

[Pymavlink's own documentation](https://mavlink.io/en/mavgen_python/) says it can be used with Python 2.7+ and Python 3.5+. So, that leaves safe candidate versions of Python for Pymavlink 2.4.8 to be 2.7, 3.5, 3.6.

I personally have had it working for me with Python 2.7 on Windows 10.

Comment: I've got it working with python 2.7 but I had to install these: sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev

Comment: @SamanthaHill Ohkay. I was struggling with the installation on Ubuntu a few days ago. I'll give it a try again I guess. 

The main issue I was facing was compatibility problem. Dronekit requires pymavlink 2.4.8 or below to work while Mavproxy requires some higher version of pymavlink, hence the reason for the mavproxy warning when downgrading pymavlink. But for some weird reason, for me Mavproxy still worked on Windows but not on Linux.

Comment: Ahan so the way I fixed that was by realizing Mavproxy is run independent of dronekit. It doesn't need to be inside the virtual environment hence both can use their own versions of pymavlink ^_^